# Android adapter for a custom layout listview based on a class

Tags: android, adapter

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Vizita {
     public int icon;
        public String titlu;
        public String loc;
        public String idviz;
        public Vizita(){
            super();
        }

        public Vizita(int icon, String titlu, String loc, String idviz) {
            super();
            this.icon = icon;
            this.titlu = titlu;
            this.loc = loc;
            this.idviz = idviz;
        }
}
```

I use AsyncTask to retrieve a JSON array from a PHP. All works perfect for simple layout of listview. But I want to use a more complex layout, so I designed one that uses all 4 values from Vizita.class above. But I do not know how to set the adapter for it, because the way I try it, gives me errors.

Of course I am trying to do it in onPostExecute, like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
{...}
JSONArray lststat;
{...}
public JSONArray liststatus() {
    JSONArray jdata=post.getserverdataX(url_connectX);
    return jdata;
}   

class asyncpost extends AsyncTask< String, String, String > {
Vizita weather_data[];
....
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
VizitaAdapter adapter = new VizitaAdapter(MyActivity.this,R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);   
...}
```

And in doInBackground I am processing the JSON like this:

```
lststat = liststatus();
JSONObject json_data; 
try {
     int length = lststat.length();
     Vizita weather_data[] = new Vizita[length];
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     {
        json_data = lststat.getJSONObject(i);
        weather_data[i].titlu =json_data.getString("clientnume");
        weather_data[i].idviz =json_data.getString("idvizite");
        weather_data[i].loc =json_data.getString("localitate");
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(null, e.toString());
}
```

where liststatus() is where I call the asyncTask to retrieve the needed JSONArray.

But I receive a java.lang.NullPointerException in the for loop (if I comment the setAdapter line).

I assume I did not initialize the weather_data array properly ?!?!?
If I (uncomment) set the adapter in onPostExecute I receive a crash error "Force close"
I do not receive any errors in the IDE, seeming that the syntaxes are fine.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

The code for the VizitaAdapter is bellow

```
public class VizitaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vizita>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Vizita data[] = null;

    public VizitaAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Vizita[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtLoco = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLocalitate);
            holder.txtIdviz = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtIdVizite);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Vizita weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.titlu);
        holder.txtLoco.setText(weather.loc);
        holder.txtIdviz.setText(weather.idviz);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtLoco;
        TextView txtIdviz;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you forgot initialize `Vizita` object in loop:

```
json_data = lststat.getJSONObject(i);
weather_data[i] = new Vizita();
weather_data[i].titlu =json_data.getString("clientnume");
weather_data[i].idviz =json_data.getString("idvizite");
weather_data[i].loc =json_data.getString("localitate");
```

Comment: nice catch. You were right. But still my listview remains empty. And I did a Log.e before setting the adapter and weather_data is indeed NULL. What is still wrong?

Comment: Maybe something wrong with `VizitaAdapter`. Post code or check that method `getCount` returns positive value.

Comment: I will post the code for the adapter in 2 minutes. Don't go away. Just copy/pasting. I finished adding the code. It's in the question body. Thank you

Comment: I do not see any getCount anywhere. Please check my code for the adapter above, in the question body

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Adapter is fine. Check this: `weather_data[] = new Vizita[length];` (remove first `Vizita` in begging, so you shouldn't introduce locale variable instead initialize class field)

Comment: When I used `listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);` to retrieve the JSONArray, my problem was that before the for loop I did: `List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);` instead of `listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);` So basically I RE-declared the arraylist, and that was why the listContents was null. In this case could it be something similar? Considering that before the for loop I do: `Vizita weather_data[] = new Vizita[length];` ??? I am a newbie in Java so please have patience with me...

Comment: You mean I should remove the `Vizita weather_data[];` from right bellow the onPostExecute? If I do that then in onPostExecute, weather_data cannot be resolved to a variable...

Comment: Also if I remove "Vizita" from `Vizita weather_data[] = new Vizita[length];` another error is shown by the IDE: "weather_data cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: No, keep it in asyncpost class. But when you parse JSON here:  `int length = lststat.length();
     weather_data[] = new Vizita[length]; // !HERE!
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     {
        json_data = lststat.getJSONObject(i);
        weather_data[i].titlu =json_data.getString("clientnume");
        weather_data[i].idviz =json_data.getString("idvizite");
        weather_data[i].loc =json_data.getString("localitate");
     }` you should remove introducing local variable. Hope this help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34541/discussion-between-aim-and-user1137313)

Comment: Please check my previous comment. We did it in the same time. If I do what you suggest, then the `weather_data cannot be resolved to a type` error shows.

Comment: Thank you aim. Your solution worked like a charm. I accepted your answer. Have a good day